# Make part of a string bold in Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

I've seen many people asking this question but I never seem to find a simple straight forward answer. I'm using Vue and in a component I'm displaying text coming from an object. I would like to make the text that specifies the price in bold but leave the rest of the text as is. How can I make this specific part of the string bold?

```
premiumContent: [
    {
       infoText: "Get this for only €2,99 per month:",
    },
]
```

Comment: @tony19 has right answer, anyway if you do not have possibility to change what's coming  from API, you can use `filters` with specific regex to find first `€` character, add `<b>` in front of it and after numbers, and continue as @tony19 suggests, using `v-html="inforText | filter"`

Comment: if the info text is always in that form, you can split the string by spaces `array.split(" ")` and the 4th index will always be the price

then just manipulate array[4] which holds the string $2,99

Comment: @Omar Good idea! Better yet, going from the euro symbol and go until the space is found, or just write a tiny regex to find that based on the currency (usd, eur, etc).

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit `infoText`, surround the price with [`<b>` tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b):

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      premiumContent: [
        {
          infoText: "Get this for only <b>€2,99</b> per month:",
        },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Then insert it into an element's [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) using the [`v-html` directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html):

```html
<div v-for="content of premiumContent"
     v-html="content.infoText">
</div>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/LYxbQOW)

Comment: I guess his issue is finding the price in the string, and then updating it.

Comment: That's possible, but the OP should clarify that detail in the question. :)